# changing the space after chapter title and figures

Tags: spacing, titles

How do I change the space between chapter titles and after figures/tables to certain amount?
[image: Chapter title]  [image: Figures]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec} %required for section titles
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{0.5in}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[verbose]{cite}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[left=1.0in,
            right=1.0in,
            top=1.0in,
            bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
    },
    cmhplot/.style={color=black,mark=none,line width=1pt,<->},
    soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} 
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
%\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
%\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{3em}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}



\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}


\doublespacing 
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}
    %DO NOT USE \maketitle
    \newgeometry{top=2.0in}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \large
    %\vspace*{2in}
    Title\\
    %\vspace{1in}
    By\\
    N
    \vspace{.5in}
    \end{center}
    
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
    %\vspace*{2in}
    T\\
    %\vspace{1in}
    By\\
    \\
    \vspace*{1in}
    \\~\\~\\~\\
    The University \\
    \\~\\
    
    \end{center}



\chapter*{}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    Copyright \copyright\ 2022
    
    \bigskip
    
    \bigskip
    
    All Rights Reserved
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{center}
    
    \restoregeometry
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
    %\large
    \subfile{Sections/Abstract}
        
    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
        \subfile{Sections/Acknowledge}
        
    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
    \subfile{Sections/Dedication}
    
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
    \tableofcontents
    
    %\chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}
    %\cleardoublepage
    
    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    \noindent
    \subfile{Sections/Los}
    
    %\chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF TABLES}
    %\cleardoublepage
    
    
    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    \subfile{Sections/Loa}
    

    \cleardoublepage
    \cleardoublepage
    \large
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}}
\section{Background}
\subfile{Sections/Background}

%\newpage
\section{Questions}
\noindent
\label{Quest}
\subfile{Sections/quest}

\section{Limitations}
\label{Limit}
\subfile{Sections/Limit}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
\subfile{Sections/Relworks}


\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
\subfile{Sections/conclusion}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} 

\clearpage

%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
\subfile{Sections/Vita}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already measured the space added by the environments, an easy way to proceed is to remove this space (by inserting a negative space) and then add the desired space (0.6 inches)

In the first case this is done using the optional parameter of the command `\titleformat` for code to be executed after.

In the second case just after `\end{figure}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec} %required for section titles
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{0.5in}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[verbose]{cite}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[left=1.0in,
right=1.0in,
top=1.0in,
bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
    },
    cmhplot/.style={color=black,mark=none,line width=1pt,<->},
    soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
}
\tikzset{>=stealth}


%\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]
%{⟨format⟩}
%{⟨label⟩}
%{⟨sep⟩}
%{⟨before-code}
%[⟨after-code⟩]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
{\centering\normalfont\large}
{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}
{0pt}
{}
[% after code <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\vspace*{-0.74in} % remove inserted space <<<
\vspace*{0.6in}% add desired space  <<<<
]

\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} 
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
%\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
%\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{3em}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}

\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}


\doublespacing 
\raggedbottom 

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY dummy text <<<

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Background}
\kant[9]
\begin{figure}[hb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Usage of Lights I}
        \label{fig:one}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Usage of Lights II}
        \label{fig:two}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Usage of devices}
    \label{fig:graphs}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-0.34in} % remove inserted space <<<
\vspace*{0.6in} % add desired space  <<<<
\kant[11]

\end{document}
```

By commenting out or removing `\vspace*{0.6in}` it is possible to verify that the white space disappears.

[image: b]